# What is name for the following situation?

Tags: linear-transformations, terminology

Consider two bases  $<u_1,u_2, \ldots, u_n>$  and $<v_1,v_2, \ldots, v_n>$ in a  vector space  $L$. Suppose that a linear operator $A:L\to L$ has the identical  matriсes in both bases.

Is there a special terminology for this case?

Answer (score 2):

If $S$ is the linear operator that takes the first basis to the second, you're saying that
$S^{-1} A S = A$, i.e. that $A$ commutes with $S$.

Comment: I know  it, but  I aksed for terminology